# How can I calculate max value, if I know just number of records, minimal value and average value of all records?

Tags: analysis, statistics

How can I calculate max value or all possible and relevant maximum values, if I know number of records, minimal value and average value of all records?

For example:
Number of records (persons): 92
Minimal increase: 20€
Average increase: 33€
Max increase for person: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot calculate an exact maximum with that information, but you can put wide bounds on it.

The highst possible maximum will be $33 + \frac{91}{1}\times(33-20) = 1034$, happening when all but one of the values are at the minimum

The lowest possible maximum will be $33 + \frac{1}{91}\times(33-20) =33.142857\ldots$, happening when all but one of the values are at the maximum